# Cannot access member 'match' of undefined in geth

Tags: ethereum, geth

I am testing with rinkiby in ethereum geth environment (using light node.). By building the contract with solidity, the contract has been deployed correctly. If I try to access a function in that instance, I got a "match" error. I don't use "match" anywhere in the program source code, but I don't know which part is the problem. Can I analyze more solidity code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `web3` version.

[reference](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/898).